# Using regex to replace strange characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

After importing some products from a csv strange characters have shown up on the page and it would be too much work to manually go to each product and remove them so I made this script to deploy on that product page and remove them.

```
$(function() {
    var p_desc = $(".rte").html();
    var re = /\?ÕÌ_|Š|š|Ž|ž|À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å|Æ|Ç|È|É|Ê|Ë|Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ñ|Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ö|Ø|Ù|Ú|Û|Ü|Ý|Þ|ß|à|á|â|ã|ä|å|æ|ç|è|é|ê|ë|ì|í|î|ï|ð|ñ|ò|ó|ô|õ|ö|ø|ù|ú|û|ý|þ|ÿ|_Œ‚|__|_/g;
    var result = p_desc.replace(re, ' ');
    var new_p_desc = result.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "").replace(/\?/g, '');
    $(".rte").html(new_p_desc);
});
```

My script is working fine but not sure if it could be made better. Was this the best way to go about it?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the strange characters? There is probably a better solution that deleting them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### RegEx Improvements

The regex can be shortened by using [case-insensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) match with `i` flag. We can remove the characters which are added as both lowercase and uppercase in the regex.

After removing lowercase characters regex will be as below

```
\?ÕÌ_|Š|Ž|À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å|Æ|Ç|È|É|Ê|Ë|Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ñ|Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ö|Ø|Ù|Ú|Û|Ü|Ý|Þ|ß|ð|ÿ|_Œ‚|__|_
```

Here's [live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/Ml6gKe/1) of regex

The regex can be further improved by using [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will make the matches faster than OR conditions

```
\?ÕÌ_|_Œ‚|[ŠŽÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßðÿ_]+
```

Adding `+` quantifier also has positive effect on the number of steps taken to match characters when the characters in the character class are consecutive/adjacent to each other.

Here's the demo on RegEx101, [without `+` quantifier](https://www.regex101.com/r/Ml6gKe/2)<sup>[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pbAf.png)</sup> and [with `+` quantifier](https://www.regex101.com/r/Ml6gKe/3)<sup>[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A9Ld.png)</sup> applied on the same data. Note that in these demos, PHP is selected as the *steps taken to match* is not shown for JavaScript. Also, the regex is different, it also contains lowercase counterparts of those special characters as `i` flag is not working with PHP and don't want to apply `u`(Unicode) flag as it is not supported in JavaScript.

These demos are created only to show difference when `+` is applied on character class. The effect should be similar in JavaScript.

Note that the `__`(two underscores) are redundant as `_` is already added in character class and with `g` flag it'll remove all occurrences.

### Method Chaining

As `replace` returns a string, any other string method can be called on it. Multiple calls to `replace` can be chained.

```
str.replace(someRegexOrString, someString)
    .replace(someOtherRegexOrString, someOtherString);
```

This is equivalent to

```
var temp = str.replace(someRegexOrString, someString);
var result = temp.replace(someOtherRegexOrString, someOtherString);
```

### Replacing HTML

jQuery [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) accepts a function which will receive the current `innerHTML` of the element on which the method is called as parameter and replaces the returned content to the element.

The code can be written as

```
$('.rte').html(function(index, currentHTML) {
    return doSomeOperationOn(currentHTML);
});
```

### Complete Code

With above changes, the code will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var regex = /\?ÕÌ_|_Œ‚|[ŠŽÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßðÿ_]+/gi;

    $('.rte').html(function(i, oldHTML) {
        return oldHTML.replace(regex, ' ')
            .replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]|\?/g, '');
    });
});
```

`$(document).ready(function() {` is more readable than `$(function() {`. So, you may also consider using more expressive form.

Answer (score 2):

The code may be correct in itself, but it does the wrong thing.

If by *strange* you mean *unknown to someone who only knows English*, that's no excuse for removing any letters you don't know. Would you really want to look at street signs for `Cafs` (which were legitimate `Cafés` before)?

If you get strange character sequences like `Ã¶`, that's an [encoding problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and you need to fix it properly instead of hiding it.

If you really have to keep your code, at least be honest and replace each unknown character with a question mark or the Unicode replacement character so that it is clearly visible that something unexpected happened here.